# Detect Browser (possible return values)

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I did find this answer:

```
function get_browser(){
        var ua=navigator.userAgent,tem,M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || []; 
        if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
            tem=/\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || []; 
            return 'IE '+(tem[1]||'');
            }   
        if(M[1]==='Chrome'){
            tem=ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
            if(tem!=null)   {return 'Opera '+tem[1];}
            }   
        M=M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
        if((tem=ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!=null) {M.splice(1,1,tem[1]);}
        return M[0];
        }

    var br = get_browser();
```

However I am not sure what all possible return values are. I actually only need the main browsers. I tested myself and for Firefox Browser it is "Firefox". But I don't know how to test for other browsers without installing them

Comment: Are you aware that "feature detection" is generally considered a much better option than "browser detection"?

Comment: I need the browser detection for stats. Not for layout or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could install one of those plugins like [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) to test your code without installing all the browsers; however, the fact that you can install a plugin to make believe it is in fact a different browser is prove that your method is not infallible.

Using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is a better approach because it uses feature detection but you will still have to code which features are supported in which browsers.

If you Google you'll find other Javascript libraries that do this already but if you are not concerned about a user changing the userAgent property via a plugin, then simply read the "User-Agent" header in the request on the server-side and you are done.

Comment: I only need the browser for stats. Why should I bother if user agent could be changed? (serious question)

Comment: @yoshi I updated my answer a little bit. Hopefully that answers your question. The bottom line is that it is very tricky to detect a browser with a 100% accuracy. The method you showed is very unreliable and so are others that use feature detection, but to a less extent.

Comment: I could get it in PHP like this `if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE) $browser = "Firefox";` but the script gets called a million times in a second and I want to reduce a decrease in performance. I am not sure though...

Comment: @yoshi why would it "be called a million times in a second" if you are not submitting the form?

Comment: It is not for a submitted form, it is for visitor stats. Million times in a second might be exaggerated but in a minute is actually true. So is this a wrong approach?

Comment: Then why do you think the thing will be called "a million times a second"? The bottom line is that if you need to have visitor stats you will have to submit the data from the client side back to the server  in order to record it. Otherwise, how do you expect to keep track of the browser version from the client side? How do you think you'll be able to store information about your visitors if you only read it using Javascript, meaning on the client-side in the browser of each user? Do you know that Javascript ONLY runs on the client-side (browser)?